# Not able to connect mongodb atlas cluster to node js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');
const connectDB = async () => {
 try
 {
    await mongoose.connect(db);
    console.log("database is Connected")
 }
 catch (err) 
 {
    console.log(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
 }
}
module.exports = connectDB;
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6divK.png)

Error:
**Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/**

Answer (score 0):

please following solutions:

1. mongoose
   .connect(`mongodb://${dbConfig.HOST}:${dbConfig.PORT}/${dbConfig.DB}`, {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   })

2. MongoDB Atlas -> NetworkAccess -> Edit -> Allowed Access from Anywhere
3. Are you using proxy?? please try with different network connection first and try it. It is working for me.